# (Windows) Program fails to run on particular machine

Tags: windows

When trying to run my executable program on a Windows Server 2008 R2 (x64), it fails immediately and Windows says "Program (x64) has stopped working".
The same executable works on many other machines.
Even on other machines with the same OS.

The program comes with its own Dlls in the folder.
Even if it would require other Dlls that arent present i think the system would say so?

Here is the output from Windows Event Viewer:

```
Faulting application name: dscp.exe, version: 19.0.0.398, time stamp: 0x5d8b42ef
Faulting module name: VERSION.dll_unloaded, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x4a5be082
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000007fefbcc15b4
Faulting process id: 0x1db4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d5744a0d493693
Faulting application path: C:\TEMP\DebugW\dscp.exe
Faulting module path: VERSION.dll
Report Id: 50adb64b-e03d-11e9-a7b2-000c29b302dd
```

I have looked up VERSION.dll and it seems to be a Windows system Dll.

I dont' know how to debug this issue.

Comment: First obvious step is to use a debugger to see what is going on. The stack trace will hopefully indicate what line of your program is causing the problem. Looks like you're calling into an unloaded DLL.

Comment: @Raymond Chen, The problem is i can't install VS on this machine and also i can't remote-debug because the process exits immediately, so there is nothing to attach to.

Comment: What about a lightweight debugger like ntsd? You can install it as a just-in-time debugger, or via Image File Execution Options so it's always run for a specific process. Maybe you can ask Windows Error Reporting to generate a dump file.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know these possibilites. I got a dmp file with Windows Error Reporting now, but the stack is extremely shallow and not helpfull: 
`> 000007fefbcc15b4() Unknown
  000007fe00000000() Unknown`

Comment: That's because the code has been unloaded. You'll have to reconstruct the stack to a point where there is code again, or load the symbols for the unloaded DLL so the debugger can trace back through it. If this is in the middle of a function call inside VERSION.dll, then you can look to see if any other thread is calling FreeLibrary to free the library out from under this thread. You'll just have to be creative with the tools and clues you have.

Comment: We have the same problem on windows 7. Did you made any progress???

Comment: @ThomasG. No unfortunately. Struggling with Windbg but not gone any farther as seeing the same stack as above.